# How can I remove the grid lines during transformation in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, perspective

I'm trying to change the perspective of a layer in GIMP, but it's very difficult to see what I'm doing while there's this enormous grid over the selection. Is there any way I can disable this?

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apUqQ.png)

Comment: Did you try to zoom in ? The grid won't disturb that much anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the use of computer software without a clear photographic context; not all questions about graphics editors are on-topic just because they *can* be used for photographic applications.

Answer (score 7):

In the tool options for the perspective tool, under "Guides", you can select "No guides". There are other options, as well, for a sparser grid, etc.

[image]

Comment: But the grid instantly comes right back as soon you go to actually work with perspective or rotate. I have version 2.8.14.